# Write to Cells in a for-loop with EPPLUS result in duplicate values

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

I do not understand why the following code write 2,2,2 to Excel while it should be 0,1,2. The code is straightforward - create an **ExcelPackage**, add a **Worksheet**, and iterate a loop to write values to a cells.

```
using (ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage())
{
    p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Foo");
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        p.Workbook.Worksheets["Foo"].Cells[1, 1, 1, 1 + j].Value = j;
    p.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"C:\FooFolder\Foo.xlsx"));
}
```

[image]

Comment: p.Workbook.Worksheets["Foo"].Cells[1, 1+j].Value = j;

Comment: Epplus supports loading from collection in a single shot. Much better than writing in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writting in a range instead of a unique cell. With `Cells[1, 1, 1, 1 + j]` you are writting from cell 1,1 to cell  1,1+j : the complete range take the assigned value.

Use `Cells[1, j, 1, 1 + j]` instead

Comment: Didn't realize I was setting a range instead of a cell to the `Cells`.